# We're sorry, but something went wrong. – Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

Heroku gives me "We're sorry, but something went wrong".

I'm trying to deploy my Rails project to Heroku, it's sqlite based.

I've got these files in my gem file to fix previous problems

```
 group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
 end
```

And this is the log Heroku provided, so far no errors

```
          -----> Removing .DS_Store files
          -----> Ruby app detected
          -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
          -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
          -----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
                 Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
                 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
                 Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
                 Fetching git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
                 Installing rake 10.3.2
                 Installing i18n 0.6.9
                 Installing minitest 5.3.5
                 Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
                 Installing builder 3.2.2
                 Installing erubis 2.7.0
                 Installing rack 1.5.2
                 Installing mime-types 1.25.1
                 Installing json 1.8.1
                 Installing polyglot 0.3.5
                 Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
                 Installing sass 3.2.19
                 Installing thor 0.19.1
                 Installing execjs 2.2.0
                 Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
                 Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
                 Installing highline 1.6.21
                 Installing hike 1.2.3
                 Installing multi_json 1.10.1
                 Installing icalendar 2.1.0
                 Installing options 2.3.2
                 Using bundler 1.6.3
                 Installing bcrypt 3.1.7
                 Installing tilt 1.4.1
                 Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
                 Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
                 Installing will_paginate 3.0.6
                 Installing tzinfo 1.2.1
                 Installing rack-test 0.6.2
                 Installing warden 1.2.3
                 Installing rdoc 4.1.1
                 Installing treetop 1.4.15
                 Installing bourbon 3.2.3
                 Installing uglifier 2.5.1
                 Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
                 Installing progress_bar 1.0.2
                 Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
                 Installing sprockets 2.11.0
                 Installing sdoc 0.4.0
                 Installing activesupport 4.1.1
                 Installing mail 2.5.4
                 Installing actionview 4.1.1
                 Installing climate_control 0.0.3
                 Installing activemodel 4.1.1
                 Installing jbuilder 2.1.1
                 Installing actionpack 4.1.1
                 Installing cocaine 0.5.4
                 Installing activerecord 4.1.1
                 Installing actionmailer 4.1.1
                 Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.3
                 Installing railties 4.1.1
                 Using paperclip 4.1.1 from git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git (at master)
                 Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
                 Installing devise 3.2.4
                 Installing jquery-rails 3.1.0
                 Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
                 Installing rails 4.1.1
                 Installing turbolinks 2.2.2
                 Installing rails4-autocomplete 1.1.0
                 Installing pg 0.17.1
                 Your bundle is complete!
                 Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
                 It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
                 Post-install message from icalendar:
                 HEADS UP! iCalendar 2.0 is not backwards-compatible with 1.x. Please see the README for the new syntax
                 Post-install message from rdoc:
                 Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
                 <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
                 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
                 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
                 >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
                 Bundle completed (19.02s)
                 Cleaning up the bundler cache.
          -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
                 Running: rake assets:precompile
                 I, [2014-07-04T11:09:44.994721 #1465]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_015830e2-6769-413c-ae17-3c1d1e403a36/public/assets/application-ef6d9188f03ae958e0e7ebf51fab00fb.js
                 I, [2014-07-04T11:09:55.195306 #1465]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_015830e2-6769-413c-ae17-3c1d1e403a36/public/assets/application-dd93fb9eaa145c8045a2b6bf97786a72.css
                 Asset precompilation completed (19.06s)
                 Cleaning assets
                 Running: rake assets:clean
          -----> WARNINGS:
                 You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
                 To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
                 ruby '2.0.0'
                 # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.

                 No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
                 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
          -----> Discovering process types
                 Procfile declares types -> (none)
                 Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

          -----> Compressing... done, 50.3MB
          -----> Launching... done, v6
                 http://confguide.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using locally? You're not specifying a version for Heroku, so maybe the is some version problem? Also, have a look at the logs to see what they say `heroku logs --app <appname>`

Comment: @jordelver ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]. Added ruby '2.1.2' to my gemfile. Still the same issue.

Heroku logs gives me the following: http://pastebin.com/5xCZA3Gj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the logs it looks like you have not run `rake db:migrate`

For Heroku run the following command

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3#rake-and-database-migrations

Comment: Nice! That fixed it. Any clue how I can transfer my sqlite entries to the Heroku db?

Comment: you can write a script that will fetch from sqlite and dump into other db